# Sending e-mails with php

Tags: php, html, email

I have a html bootstrap page, and it's being hosted by http://www.awardspace.com, which supports PHP. I upload everything with Filezilla, and I used a bootstrap template for my contact page. I followed the instructions that came with it, and I want the contact page to mail to koploper77@gmail.com. When I go to the page (http://aviationsite.atwebpages.com/contact.html), and when I fill in every form, it says that the email has been send but I don't actually receive them. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you need to use php to send that form, show us your code

Comment: share ur email sending script?

Comment: Did you check whether your host supports sending emails or whether there a conditions for the sender of the email (e.g. address)?

Comment: my php file: https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-modern-business/blob/master/bin/contact_me.php and here is my contact page: https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-modern-business/blob/master/contact.html I replaced the standard email with koploper77@gmail.com

Comment: Please, add relevant information inside your question instead of giving url in comment

Answer (score 0):

**1.** 
Gmail can block your email.
Try to tempmail https://temp-mail.org/pl/
I have that same problem becouse postfix in my server not have good configuration.

**2.**
Use smtp connection from any other mail account to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should check your spambox if it isn't located over there you could try the following (I assume the bootstrap template will work but just to make sure)

```
<?php
$_POST['fromemail'] = $from;
$to      = 'koploper77@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = "From: webmasteremailyourwanttosendfomr@example.com";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

If that works you can try to change the `"From: webmasteremailyourwanttosendfomr@example.com";` to `"From: $from"` 
and then try

```
$message = $_POST['messagefield'];
$subject = $_POST['subjectfield'];
```

Hope this helps you out :)